# Is cupy.einsum always synchronizing?

Tags: cupy

It seems that cupy.einsum always synchronizes. See this:

```py
import cupy as cp
import time

N = 3000
A = cp.random.rand(N, N)
B = cp.random.rand(N, N)

print("matmul")
T1 = time.time()
for i in range(5):
    t1 = time.time()
    C = cp.matmul(A, B)
    t2 = time.time()
    print(t2-t1)
cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
T2 = time.time()
print('cumulated synchronization time', T2-T1)

print("\neinsum")
T1 = time.time()
for i in range(5):
    t1 = time.time()
    C = cp.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, B)
    t2 = time.time()
    print(t2-t1)
cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
T2 = time.time()
print('cumulated synchronization time', T2-T1)
```

And the result is:

```
matmul
0.013315200805664062
0.0006041526794433594
0.0001671314239501953
0.00013303756713867188
0.00011086463928222656
cumulated synchronization time 2.4193735122680664

einsum
0.4733295440673828
0.46896910667419434
0.4687662124633789
0.4687614440917969
0.4690871238708496
cumulated synchronization time 2.3490567207336426
```

So einsum synchronizes at every run. And the question is: why this is so? Can this behavior be changed?

Regards, Marek

Comment: According to the profiler output, `cupy.einsum` does not synchronize, but it seems that additional memory copy is happening for input ndarrays, which isn't the case in `cupy.matmul`.